# Best approach for coding a painting app on iOS / iPad

Tags: ipad, ios13, swift5, metal, xcode11

I’m trying to build a drawing/painting app for the iPad, with textured brush tips and paper.

So far, all drawing app example codes I've come across seem to work by stroking a path. However, I'd like to actually apply a texture all along the path, to simulate say, an oil brush, or charcoal.

Here is an example of a brush tip texture: [Bursh tip](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SL0t2.jpg)

The result when painting with the same brush tip: [Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BEb4z.jpg)

In the results, the top output is what it looks like when the "brush tip" texture is applied far apart along the path.

The bottom result is the texture applied with very small steps along the path. Those who've worked in Photoshop with custom brushes will find this familiar.

I had once prototyped this in Processing years ago (I've since lost the source code), and got it to work in real-time.

In Processing, I converted both the brush tip PNG and the canvas (or the image I'm painting on to) into an array of integers. Then, I simply copied the values from the brush tip to the canvas texture, at the appropriate index. At the end of the cycle, I displayed the image, for that time-step. Repeat this dozens of times in-between each point returned by the mouse.

How would I approach this in iOS, and in real-time? I tried this (https://blog.avenuecode.com/how-to-use-uikit-for-low-level-image-processing-in-swift) but it's way too slow.

This makes me believe Metal might be the only way forward. Is that true, or am complicating this unnecessarily?

Thank you for any guidance!

PS. I'm coding in Swift 5, targeting iOS 13, in Xcode 11.5.

Comment: Re being too slow, are you doing a debug build or a release build? On device or simulator? I’d suggest only drawing conclusions re performance w optimized build on physical device...

Comment: While Metal is the ultimate way to go in that it offers the most flexibility and performance potential, it is also the most challenging to use. A compromise might be the CoreGraphics API (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coregraphics). It should be fairly easy to implement the above example, and I expect performance would be considerably better than manually manipulating the pixels on the CPU (as described in that example you mentioned).

Comment: @Rob, Thank you for the suggestion. Since I've only worked in Processing before this, I wasn't aware the simulator may cause performance hits even though it's running on a much more powerful machine. Will check on the device.

Comment: @Idoogy, Thank you as well. New to coding in iOS and Xcode in general, and will digest the CoreGraphic documentation, before going for something much more challenging like Metal.

Comment: FWIW, it’s not that the device is necessarily faster than your computer running the simulator, but rather is just different (for pure computations, the simulator is likely faster, but for graphics stuff dedicated iOS device hardware can sometimes be faster). The bigger factor, though, is the choice of doing an optimized release build rather than an up optimized debug build.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome!

I recommend you check out Core Image. It's Apple's framework for image processing (on a higher level than Metal, though it can integrate with Metal). Unfortunately, the documentation is a bit out-dated, but I'm sure you can translate it into Swift.

[Here](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/CoreImaging/ci_feedback_based/ci_feedback_based.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001185-CH5-SW2) Apple describes how you would realize a painting app with Core Image and [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/samplecode/CIMicroPaint/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40009218) you can download the corresponding sample project.

Comment: Thank you, Frank! That MicroPainting example is exactly what I was looking for, just need to translate it for Swift. Cheers.